# SQL - Select N columns from table repeatedly

Tags: sql-server

I need to select first N column from tableA and insert into to another tableB. This needs to be done till all column from tableA moved to tableB.

Example,

```
tableA:    
         A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2   
         10,10,20,20,30,30  
          11,11,22,22,33,33
```

convert to like this

```
tableB -     
         X, Y   
         10,10   
         11,11  
         20,20  
         22,22  
         30,30                 
         33,33
```

I can get this output using union as given below

```
insert into tableB  
select A1,A2 from tableA  
UNION  
select B1,B2 from tableA  
UNION  
select C1,C2 from tableA
```

but I would like know best and optimized way.

Comment: If you are OK with duplicate values use `union all`

Comment: Do you have any performances issues with your solution?

Comment: Yes. Scan count is equal to number of select statement and logical read is also high since it scanning whole tableA on each select

Comment: The problem here is that you're treating tables like spreadsheets. Despite their superficial resemblance, they're very different beasts. The columns within a table should be a fixed, known set, and each column should be a different "type" of data. There therefore aren't general mechanisms to perform operations "for each column" or "until all columns are consumed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
      cj.x, cj.y
FROM table1 t
CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES
            (t.a1, t.a2)
          , (t.b1, t.b2)
          , (t.c1, t.c2)
         ) AS cj (x, y)
```

Using cross apply with values allows you to generate multiple output rows for each input row. Simply layout the column pairs for each output row as indicated above. This will reduce the number of scans over the source table to 1.

You do need to recognize that the data types need to be compatible in their new column positions  of x and y (e.g. a1 as date, b1 as string, and c1 as decimal all into a single x column would fail).

For more information on this use of CROSS APPLY and VALUES as an UNPIVOT, I recommend [Spotlight on UNPIVOT, Part 1](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com.au/2010/02/spotlight-on-unpivot-part-1.html) by Brad Schultz